# Are there Haskell equivalents for the `webbrowser` Python package?

Tags: haskell, scripting, libraries

Python has the very convenient `webbrowser` package, which includes a `webbrowser.open()` function which allows to open a browser on a location, even on a file in the local filesystem. This way Python programs can for example generate a web document as an output and present it to the user. Which Haskell packages expose a similar functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package named [open-browser](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.2/open-browser-0.2.1.0/Web-Browser.html):

```
$ stack ghci open-browser
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-6.14 from implicit global project's config file: /home/sibi/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
open-browser-0.2.1.0: using precompiled package
Configuring GHCi with the following packages:
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
λ> import Web.Browser
λ> openBrowser "https://www.google.com"
True
```

This opens the google page in my default browser Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. The [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/open-browser) refers to a Github repo which does not exist, while [this repo](https://github.com/yamadapc/open-browser) seems to match the package